# Convert series of nested promises to @Effect

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

Is there a way to convert a set of nested async promises into an @Effect?

I have a transaction that uses multiple async http calls where I have to wait for a result before going to the next step and any error aborts the transaction and sends an error message to the user.

I'm fairly new to rxjs and it seems like I can kind of get the same action as "Promise...then" with exhaustMap, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it and capture the errors along the way.

My goal is to move the entire transaction (currently in a service) to an ngrx @Effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would do multiple effects with each effect dispatching a new action. It's just more comprehensible and you get a log in the reduce-devtools.

```
@Effect()
public makeFirstRequest = this.actions.pipe(
    ofType<InitialAction>(ActionTypes.InitialAction),
    switchMap(action => this.myService.firstRequest(action.param)),
    map(response => new FollowUpAction(response))
);

@Effect()
public makeSecondRequest = this.actions.pipe(
    ofType<FollowUpAction>(ActionTypes.FollowUpAction),
    switchMap(action => this.myService.secondRequest(action.param)),
    map(response => new NextAction(response))
);

// and so on...
```

This way it first executes the `InitialAction` and makes the request and as soon as the request is completed it executes the `FollowUpAction`. You can pass the response as parameter of the next action. Remember that you don't have to pass the response to the next action. You can do whatever you want with the response and dispatch a new action with whatever parameters (or no parameters) you like.

And I am not sure if this is included in your question but you need observables and not promieses. If you do use promises you can simply use `from(myPromise)` provided by `rxjs` to map it into an observable.

Comment: Nice. Let me try this solution.

Comment: Just to help beacuse effects are powerful but complex on map(response => {do what you want with the "response"; return the new action that will be dispatched;})

Comment: This solution is mostly working, but when I add an if/else conditional to generate one action for success and another action for an error, I get an invalid action in the effect. Can you tell me what is the best way to add a conditional statement for the response?

`@Effect()
public makeFirstRequest = this.actions.pipe(
    ofType<InitialAction>(ActionTypes.InitialAction),
    switchMap(action => this.myService.firstRequest(action.param)),
    map(response => {
 if (success) {
  new FollowUpAction(response)
 }else{
  new ErrorAction(response)
 }})
);`

Comment: @FrancescoFortin Thanks for the hint, I'll update my answer ;)

Comment: @markelc hmmm, I would do it the same way and it should work. Are you sure both actions extend from action etc.?

Comment: I figured it out. I needed a return before each action.

Comment: Oh yeah sure. Overlooked that as well :D 
Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Let us suppose `a` and `b` are observables then you can wait for all the observables got resilved using [forkJoin](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md) method.

```
Rx.Observable.forkJoin([a,b]).subscribe(result=> {
        var resultA = result[0];
        var resultB = result[1];
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at forkJoin.

Comment: forkJoin appears to run all observables in parallel but I need to run them sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I really understand your problem but it seems like you could just use `Promise.all()` to make a collection of promises into a single promise which could then be used in your @Effects.
[See Promise.all() definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into this as well.